# В каком виде должен быть JSON, для отправки POST запроса на авторизацию в Django REST framework?

Tags: json, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

У меня стоит задача написать клиент на ASP.NET.CORE, который общается с API на Django REST framework. Программист со стороны API, скинул мне структуру API swagger. Отправляю POST запросы через POSTMAN {"username":"nik","password":"1234"} , результата никакого. Какая структура JSON должна быть для ввода данных в POSTMAN.

Описание swagger файла:`"paths": {
        "/api/login": {
            "post": {
                "operationId": "login",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "in": "body",
                        "name": "LoginParameters",
                        "schema": {
                            "properties": {
                                "username": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "password": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK",
                        "schema": {
                            "properties": {
                                "session_id": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "username": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    },
                    "400": {
                        "description": "Bad request",
                        "schema": {
                            "properties": {
                                "error": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    },
                    "401": {
                        "description": "Unauthorized"
                    }
                }
            }
        },`

Comment: Как вы делаете запрос в постмене?

Comment: JSON отправляю через вкладку body -> raw. Ответ сервера приходит 500

Comment: Сервер в дебаге? Есть конкретная ошибка? Можете скинуть?